# Is it possible to not run Buildkite for readme updates?

Tags: continuous-integration, buildkite

I have the following action on buildkite that automatically packs and deploy a package to repo manager every time a PR gets merged into master.
But I would like that it was not run if my update is only a README.md update, is it possible to do so?

Comment: Could the [Monorepo plugin](https://github.com/buildkite-plugins/monorepo-diff-buildkite-plugin?tab=readme-ov-file#monorepo-diff-buildkite-plugin) help in your case?